# Elasticsearch : 200 million aliases ?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, system-design

I watched [Shay Banon's talk](https://www.elastic.co/videos/big-data-search-and-analytics) where he brings about an interesting design pattern for creating 'per user indices'. He talks about creating a single index and using aliases with a routing key to represent each user 'index'. Is there a limit on the number of aliases you can create ?

I saw [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-1mln-aliases-is-really-slow/16208) where somebody was having problems creating 1 million indices and explains how index templating would be a good idea to optimize things.

I am planning to work on something similar but the scale is in the order of 200 million aliases. Is this possible today ? Anybody has any numbers around it ?

Should I be thinking of a completely different design or would the same pattern hold ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would create a huge cluster state with 200 million aliases, so I dont think that this would work.